# "I feel sorry for what I've done" = "I'm sorry for what I've done"?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> I feel sorry for what I've done.

Does it mean "I'm sorry for what I've done."?

Does "feel sorry" have this meaning? I couldn't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Yes. If you _feel sorry_, you have feelings of regret. The dictionary can't cover all possible phrases including the word _feel_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Feeling sorry would normally imply actually *being* sorry.

But I can conceive of exceptions to that. For example:

> I just got the toxicology results back and I was right; i *had* been drugged! And so although I *feel* sorry for what I’ve done, I know I shouldn’t because it wasn’t on purpose.

Or

> Me? Feel sorry? Oh sure. I put up with his nonsense for a year, and never complained once; not even when he ate all the cheesecake *and* the muffins! But then I eat the last half a grape and *I’m* the antisocial pig? Fine. Whatever. What. Ever! I feel sorry for what I’ve done. Someone should punish me now, like the malicious, evil criminal I clearly am.